# can we give same value in ResourceBundleMessageSource as properties name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

message bundle :

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

Here, the file called messages.propertie

```
greeting=hi!
```

Then using the message tag :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<spring:message code="greeting" />
```

the value in property tag ie 'message' should be same as my property file name ie 'message.propertie' and spring:message  is predefined dag given by spring or it is nothing but my property file name??

Comment: Is this working? `basename` generally is a a fully-qualified classpath location. The `spring:message` tag provides you with internationalization support. The text `message` has nothing to do with your file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `spring:message` is a name decided by Spring. You decide the property file name to get strings from by using `basename`.

See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html).